# "But if it makes some people *feel better use* the right vocabulary"

Tags: grammar

I was reading a  transcript of an interview about AI [here](https://futurism.com/blake-lemoine-google-interview) and I came across this part:

> There are a lot of different metaphors to use. I've used the kid
> metaphor before. It is, however, very important to remember: these
> things aren't human.
>
> So even if it's debatable on whether "thinking" is an appropriate word
> — and I think at this point, language models are doing something
> analogous to thinking, though I understand that there are technical
> experts who disagree with that — I think most people can see, "okay,
> there's some kind of thinking and understanding going on in these
> systems." But they do not do it the same way humans do, and we should
> be studying them to understand what those differences are, so that we
> can understand better how these systems come up with the answers that
> they do. [...]
>
> *So the question of sentience might be a distraction?*
>
> I don't like playing those word games. **But if it makes some people
> feel better use the right vocabulary**, okay, fine, whatever floats
> your boat.

Shouldn't "use" in the bolded clause be "using"?
As far as I know, we would say "I feel better **doing** this" and not "I feel better do this".

Am I missing something?

Comment: Seems to me that the speaker likely slipped up and that they meant to say, “if it makes some people feel better **to** use the right vocabulary…”

Comment: IMHO. It's just a typo. -  Yes, it should be "using".

Answer (score 2):

This is an imperative clause in a conditional sentence, and the imperative here is giving advice, rather than a direct order. It could be paraphrased with a modal verb, and more punctuation:

> If it makes some people feel better, you **should** use the right vocabulary.  Okay? Fine! Whatever floats your boat(!)

It is worth noting that it is possible that this is a mistake, and the author actually intends something like

> If it makes some people feel better **to** use the right vocabulary, that's okay. It's fine!  Whatever floats your boat(!)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the interview was recorded and the journalist chose to transcribe Blake Lemoine's responses. In which case, I suspect the former Google employer paused between “better” and “use” while he was probably thinking of what to say next. Note the use of "your" in the  expression “whatever floats ***your*** boat”, if there had been a typo, Lemoine ought to have said, “whatever floats ***their*** boat”.

> I don't like playing those word games. But if it makes some people feel better; [*pause*] use the right vocabulary, okay, fine, whatever floats your boat.

If I were that journalist, I would've modified the punctuation to illustrate this sense of irritation or exasperation.

> But if it makes some people feel better — use the *right* vocabulary. Okay, fine. Whatever floats your boat.